# Nested attributes not being inserted into table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, nested-attributes

I have a situation where one of my nested fields is being passed to parameters but is not being inserted into the table.

My model `Company` `has_one :incorporation`.  Incorporation has, right now anyway, one field, nested into the `Company` form as follows

```
<%= simple_form_for @company, url: url_for(action: @caction, controller: 'incorporations'), html: {id:"incorporationform"}, remote: false, update: { success: "response", failure: "error"} do |company| %>
    ...
    <%= company.simple_fields_for :incorporation do |f| %>
        <div class="padded-fields">
            <div class="form_subsection">
                <%= f.input :trademark_search, as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Would you like us to do a trademark search and provide advice regarding any issues we identify in relation to the name you have selected?', input_html: { class: 'form-control radio radio-false' } %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

The `new` and `create` methods in the controller are as follows

```
def new
    @user=current_user
    @company = @user.companies.build
    @incorporation = @company.build_incorporation
    @action = "new"
    @caction = "create"
    @remote=false
end

def create
    @snapshot="incorporation"
    @company = current_user.companies.build(company_params)
    @incorporation = @company.build_incorporation

    if @company.save
        current_user.companies << @company
        if params[:final_submit]
            redirect_to incorporations_index_path
        else
            redirect_to edit_incorporation_path(@incorporation), notice: "Successfuly saved incorporation info."
        end
    else
        render 'new', notice: "Something went wrong; form unable to be saved."
    end
end
```

**The problem** is that when I select one of the radio buttons in the simple fields, the log shows that the data is sent to the parameters:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",..., "company"=>{..."incorporation_attributes"=>{"trademark_search"=>"0"}},...}
```

But it is NOT being Inserted into the table.  Instead, a new entry is inserted but only with the `company_id`, `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at`, all of which are perfectly accurate.  There are no invalid parameter errors or anything like that.

My strong params look like this:

```
def company_params
        params.require(:company).permit(:id, :name,...,incorporation_attributes: [:title, :trademark_search, :user_id, :employee_stock_options, :final_submit, :submit, :_destroy],...)
end
```

So somehow the parameters are not linking up with the table insertion (if that makes sense).  What might be going on here?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there are some missing code, but i think issue is here:

```
@company = current_user.companies.build(company_params)
@incorporation = @company.build_incorporation
```

In first line you create company model together with incorporation model (which is present in company_params). Second line however overrides your incorporation model with a new one without any data. Since `incorporation belongs_to company`, the initial one with all the data is discarded.

Solution: remove the second line entirely and all will work.

OTHER ERRORS:

You do not need this line:

```
current_user.companies << @company
```

`@company` has already been build on `current_user.companies` scope, meaning that it already belongs to `current_user`. This will not cause any visible bugs, it's just waste of time for the server.

You are also missing `id` within `incorporation_attributes` - that means you will never be able to update or delete the data via nesting attributes (and you have _destroy field, so I assume you would like to do this at some point).

Comment: Hey thanks for having a look at this.  You were quite right about the @incorporation line.  I believe I do need the `current_user.companies << @company` because company and users are connected with a join model.

Comment: @neanderslob - Ah, yes in that case you might need it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line

```
@incorporation = @company.build_incorporation
```

from create method. This is again building the (Incorporation) record,. Nested forms will create the associated records if the parent object is created / updated,.(Company).

Answer (score 1):

You only need to "build" the associated object if you're creating a new record (the `build` record is blank):

```
def create
   @company = current_user.companies.new company_params
   @company.save #-> incorporation already set in params
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, I actually just noticed that I'd pasted in some old code above.  I made sure to change it after yesterday's coaching session :-)  I AM however, still a little hazy on the difference between `.build` and `.new`.  I'm hitting a couple other SO posts in hopes of clearing that up.

Comment: There is a difference - I read it some time ago but have misplaced the article :(